# MySQL query field as different data type

Tags: mysql, types

Just wondering if there's a way to query a field from a MySQL table as a different data type.

Let's say I have stored a field called `duration` which is type int() that I want to query using a SELECT(duration) statement, but I want the result formatted as time() data type.

Is this possible?

Regards.

Comment: I don't think so.  You can easily do that with whatever programming language you're using. Most languages have a time object that will turn an integer into a time object.

Comment: you do have Cast() or Convert() functions, but they are used only for compatible convertible types. Not sure about int to time.

Comment: @tjameson I was actaully trying to avoid that on my script XD
@Sachin Shanbhag gonna check cast() or convert()

Answer (score 1):

If you have an INT that constitutes a UNIX timestamp, you may use the [FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) function to convert it to a date string. The resulting string may then be converted to a DATETIME value with the [TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp) function.

For instance you may write:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP(FROM_UNIXTIME(1302202070));
```

Or:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP(FROM_UNIXTIME(some_column)) FROM some_table;
```

Comment: Sounds like the best option... I prefer to do it myself, because then I can specify the output format...

Comment: I found TIME_TO SEC MySQL function. SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(duration); seems to do the job, it outputs in HHH:MM:SS format.